# How to create subdomain inside subdomain in cpanel?

Tags: subdomain, cpanel, multisite

What I need to do to use subdomain inside another subdomain?

Example:

I have domain.com and I want to use site.domain.com for creating subdomains under it (user1.site.domain.com, user2.site.domain.com, user3.site.domain.com).

Answer (score 0):

I did find myself the way to do that.

1) I did create on cpanel the "site" subdomain redirecting to "public_html/"

2) I did create on cpanel the "*" subdomain redirecting to "public_html/"

That's it!